# Troubles when making C++ Opencv 4.4.0 algorithm for face recognition read frames from dataset instead of a webcam

Tags: c++, csv, opencv, visual-studio-2010, face-recognition

i used to make some modifications on a C++ and Opencv 4.4.0 algorithm for face recognition...i'm using Microsoft Visual Studio ...at first the algorithm makes 2 steps to perform face recognition : the 1st one is ADDING_FACE() function that captures frames with webcam after detecting the face of the subject and then train the **EIGENFACETRAINER()** function so that the **FACE_RECOGNITION()** function can identify subjects using this model (**eigenfacerecognizer**) (step2) ...this is the link to the original code : https://github.com/ssj-ali/Face-Detection-Recognition ....

So instead of getting frames from a webcam i want to make it use a dataset already exists with many jpg images referring to many subjects so i tried to use CSV file which holds the path to each image in the DATASET ( YALE FACE DATABASE B ) and the Label of each image, like this :

```
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject01happy.jpg;0
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject01leftlight.jpg;0
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject01noglasses.jpg;0
      .
      .
      .
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject02happy.jpg;1
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject02leftlight.jpg;1
C:\yalefaces\TrainingSet\subject02noglasses.jpg;1
```

And when i tried to pass the string holding the path to that csv file to **read_CSV()** function i got an error that says i've put a bad arguement ....here is the modification that i've done in the **FaceRec.h** file

```
static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {
  cout << filename << endl;
  std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
  if (!file) {
      string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
      CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, error_message);
  }
  string line, path, classlabel;
  while (getline(file, line)) {
      stringstream liness(line);
      getline(liness, path, separator);
      getline(liness, classlabel);
      if (!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
          images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
          labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
      }
  }
}
void addFace()
{
  //cout << "\nEnter Your Name:  ";
  //cin >> name;

  //VideoCapture capture(0);

 // if (!capture.isOpened())  
     // return ;


  //cout << "\nCapturing your face 10 times, Press 'C' 10 times keeping your face front of the camera";

  // Get the path to your CSV.
  string const fn_csv("E:\\CSV\\Sample.csv");


  
  // These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
  vector<Mat> images;
  vector<int> labels;

  // Read in the data. This can fail if no valid
  // input filename is given.
  try {
      read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
  }
  catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
      cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
      // nothing more we can do
      exit(1);
  }
  // Quit if there are not enough images for this demo.
  if (images.size() <= 1) {
      string error_message = "This demo needs at least 2 images to work. Please add more images to your data set!";
      CV_Error(Error::StsError, error_message);
  }
  // Get the height from the first image. We'll need this
  // later in code to reshape the images to their original
  // size:
  int height = images[0].rows;
.......
```

this read_csv() function already implemented in the opencv library documentation here https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html

so I've got this error:

```
OpenCV(4.4.0-dev) Error: Bad argument (No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.) in read_csv, file c:\users\ayoub\music\face-detection-recognition-master\project1c++\facerec.h, line 52
Error opening file "E:\CSV\Sample.csv". Reason: OpenCV(4.4.0-dev) c:\users\ayoub\music\face-detection-recognition-master\project1c++\facerec.h:52: error: (-5:Bad argument) No valid input file was given, please check the given filename. in function 'read_csv'
```

Can you help me please to solve this problem  and i'm wondering also if this method is useful ..if not i'll be very grateful if you could suggest me another way to make these modifications

Comment: Clearly the path to your CSV is wrong (or file permissions), this check fails: `std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in); if(!file) { ...`. Take a look if `cat "E:\CSV\Sample.csv"` outputs the content of your file.

Comment: i've tried to access the file's content using windows command prompt and yes it works..